# How do I delete all values with duplicates from list?

Tags: c#, duplicates

I can find a bunch of different ways of removing duplicates such as LINQ "Distinct().ToList()", but that still leaves the value that had duplicates, but I want to remove all values which have duplicates. If you have a list of "1, 2, 3, 3, 4" I want "1, 2, 4" to be left. Thanks!

Comment: Must the duplicates be removed from the original list, or is a new list with the duplicates removed acceptible?

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer *Linq* solution, you can try `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`:

```
 var result = list
   .GroupBy(item => item)               // group items
   .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)  // keep groups with single item only
   .SelectMany(group => group)          // flatten groups to sequence of items
   .ToList();
```

If you are looking for *in place* solution (you want to remove duplicates from *existing* list):

```
  HashSet<int> duplicates = new HashSet<int>(list
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key));

  int p = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) 
    if (!duplicates.Contains(list[i]))
      list[p++] = list[i];

  list.RemoveRange(p, list.Count - p);
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The OP wanted to _remove_ duplicates. Distinct doesnt do that

Comment: Yes, I misread the question.

Comment: Another option: `list.ToLookup(i => i).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.Key)`

Answer (score 0):

Via `GroupBy`, you can find all duplicates. With `Except`, you find all entries that are not duplicates:

```
List<int> output = input.Except(input.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key)).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTo4Cx